# Need to highlight particular pattern of text

Tags: regex, string, perl, web, pattern-matching

I have a file with some paragraphs, what i want to do is to highlight certain pattern of text/words occurring in the text file with background yellow and text color black.

```
pattern = ["enough", "too much"];
Text file = "text.txt";
```

and show it on a webpage with highlighted text for enough and too much words in the text file.

I want to use perl to do this task.
Please tell me how i can do this in optimized way.

Comment: `s/(enough|too much)/<...>$1<...>/g`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make array of all the words you want to highlight.
2. Save input file in $file variable.
3. run foreach on that array and use regular expression to replace the word with word+HTML tag.
   ie...

   foreach(@words)
   {
       $file=~r/$*/< font color=black, bgcolor=yellow>$*< /font>/g;
   }
4. save the $file again as a file with .html or .htm extension.

This was more like logic question than technical i guess.